# How to call structures inside structures using pointers?

Tags: c

I am trying to call the struct values inside the structure "Contact" so that I can input values(scanf) inside Name, Address, and Numbers using pointers and functions.

The Name, Address and Number structs are as following:

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};    

struct Address {
    int streetNumber;
    char street[41];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};

struct Numbers {
    char cell[11];
    char home[11];
    char business[11];
};

struct Contact {
  struct Name name;
  struct Address address;
  struct Numbers numbers;
};
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What have you tried? How do you enter a value of a member that is not a nested `struct` member?

Comment: Aside: you are right to store phone numbers as strings, but they are too short. My home and mobile numbers have 11 digits (without any spaces) but you need a nul terminator too. Don't be mean, and they might include a country code too. More pickiness, a house / apt number need not be `int` for example "3B Main Street".

Comment: Part of the confusion caused by your unclear question is that struct values are not called. You probably mean "access", i.e. read or write. Please confirm or elaborate.

Comment: Well i have to write inside the structures such as firstName, lastName using scanf but it has to be done inside of a function outside the main. Then, they have to be read intside the main function which i have understood.

Comment: so i have to write strings inside the variables of name, numbers and address structs

Answer (score 0):

Your `Contract` struct, as is, will not compile. When you don't use `typedef`, you need to preface all structs with the `struct` keyword. For example, this will work:

```
struct Contact {
  struct Name name;
  struct Address address;
  struct Numbers numbers;
};
```

From there, you can use it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct Contact contact;

  strcpy(contact.name.firstName, "Bob");
  printf("%s\n", contact.name.firstName);

  return 0;
}
```

Is the pointer a requirement? If so, then you can try this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct Contact* contact = malloc(sizeof(struct Contact));

  strcpy(contact->name.firstName, "Bob");
  printf("%s\n", contact->name.firstName);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That "contact.name.firstName" arrangement worked inside the main but since my scanf is displayed outside the main function, below the return 0; the contact is not recognized outside the main due to which the values are not being entered into the structure.

Comment: I have to make my functions outside the main because thats how my task is supposed to be done. The void functions were first declared above the main, called in the main function using " getName(&contacts.name);", now i dont know how to call and scanf the values such as firstname, inside the structure Name, etc.

Comment: @MysticalMamba you'd access the members in the same way. Since you're not using a pointer, you'd need to pass around entire structs, update them, then return them. Something like `someContact.name = updateName(someContact.name)`, where `updateName()` takes a `Name` struct and then returns a `Name` struct. It looks like you might have some misconceptions about how the syntax for structs work. I'd recommend finding some quick tutorials to get comfortable with normal structs, then pointers to structs.

Comment: @LearnYouACode I believe what he was asking to begin with was "How would I pass a pointer to my struct to a function so I could fill the values with `scanf`?" E.g. in `main() { ...; struct contact mycontact; fill_contact (&mycontact); ...` and then `fill_contact` does the input and stores the values.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to call the struct values inside the structure "Contact"
>   so that I can input values(scanf) inside Name, Address, and Numbers
>   using **pointers** and **functions**.

(emphasis added)

You are thinking correctly (using **pointers** to pass your structure to a **function** for filling), but do know why? In C, all parameters are *passed-by-value* and the function receives a *copy-of-the-parameter* for use within the function. If you simply passed a struct as a parameter and not the *address-of* the struct as a pointer, the function would receive a copy of the struct and any changes made within the struct would not be seen back in the calling function. All changes would be lost on the function return.

However, by passing the *address-of* the struct as a pointer, the function still receives a *copy-of* the pointer, but the pointer holds the *address-of* the struct from the calling function. That is why you must pass a pointer in order for the changes you make in your function to be seen back in the caller.

(you could also omit passing a pointer, make your function return type your struct type, dynamically allocate the struct within the function, and return a pointer to that block of memory and assign the pointer back in the caller -- but that seems beyond your task)

To pass the address of your struct to your function as a pointer, you simply declare your struct with automatic storage and then pass the address using the unary `'&'` operator. A simple example may help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int bar;
};

int fill_foo (struct foo *f)
{
    fputs ("enter bar: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", &f->bar) != 1)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main (void) {

    struct foo myfoo = { .bar = 0 };    /* named initializer */

    if (fill_foo (&myfoo))      /* validate fill, handle error */
        printf ("myfoo.bar: %d\n", myfoo.bar);
    else
        fputs ("error: fill failed.\n", stderr);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/passptrtofn
enter bar: 1234
myfoo.bar: 1234
```

If I understand your question correctly, then your question is exactly the same. The only difference being how to properly initialize and reference each member of your nested structures. The rules for referencing the members of a struct are simple, if you have a pointer, you use the `'->'` (arrow) operator to dereference the struct and obtain the value from the name. If you have the struct itself, you use the `'.'` (dot) operator to accomplish the same.

Before looking at your example, there are a couple of points to make.

1. don't use *magic numbers* in your code (except where a named constant or variable is not allowed such as for the *field-width* modifier in the `scanf` *format-string*) Instead, if you need a constant, either `#define` one (or more), or in the case where you have multiple numeric constants, a global `enum` provides a convenient way to define named constants.
2. While not an error, C generally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Turning to your example and using a global `enum` to define your constants, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* if you need constants, #define them, or use a global enum
*         ( don't use magic number in you code )
*/
enum { MI = 7, PC = 8, NO = 11, FN = 31, LN = 36, CI = 41 };

struct _name {
    char firstname[FN];
    char middleinitial[MI];
    char lastname[LN];
};    

struct _address {
    int streetnumber;
    char street[CI];
    int apartmentnumber;
    char postalcode[PC];
    char city[CI];
};

struct _numbers {
    char cell[NO];
    char home[NO];
    char business[NO];
};

struct contact {
    struct _name name;
    struct _address address;
    struct _numbers numbers;
};
...
```

(**note:** make sure your buffer sizes are adequate and don't skimp on buffer size. If there is any question, double the size.)

Note the following uses `"%[^\n]` for string input to allow for whitespace within the strings. Names can have whitespace, etc.. You can tailor the input *format specifiers* as you like, but after each input, you should empty `stdin` to remove any errant keystrokes between each input. The `empty_stdin()` function provides that below. After each input where characters remain in `stdin` it simply reads (and discards) each character that remains in `stdin` with `getchar()` until the `'\n'` (generated when the user presses *Enter*) or `EOF` is encountered, e.g.

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

A minimum input routine for your nested structs could be similar to the following. Note that "minimum" indicates many additional validations can be done to handle differing error conditions, where below, the function simply returns zero on error, one otherwise:

```
int fill_contact (struct contact *c)
{
    fputs ("\nname\n first name     : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %30[^\n]", c->name.firstname) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" middle initial : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %6[^\n]", c->name.middleinitial) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" last name      : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %35[^\n]", c->name.lastname) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();

    fputs ("\naddress\n street number  : ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", &c->address.streetnumber) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" street name    : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %40[^\n]", c->address.street) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" apartment no.  : ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", &c->address.apartmentnumber) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" postal code    : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %7[^\n]", c->address.postalcode) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" city           : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %40[^\n]", c->address.city) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();

    fputs ("\ncontact\n cell number    : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %10[^\n]", c->numbers.cell) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" home number    : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %10[^\n]", c->numbers.home) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();
    fputs (" business no.   : ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %10[^\n]", c->numbers.business) != 1)
        return 0;
    empty_stdin();

    return 1;
}
```

A simple print function will let you output the information stored will your fill routine, e.g.

```
void prn_contact (struct contact *c)
{
    printf ("\ncollected information\n"
            " %s %s. %s\n"
            " %d %s, Apt. %d\n"
            " %s, %s\n"
            " cell: %s\n home: %s\n bus.: %s\n", 
            c->name.firstname, c->name.middleinitial, c->name.lastname,
            c->address.streetnumber, c->address.street, 
            c->address.apartmentnumber, c->address.city, 
            c->address.postalcode, c->numbers.cell, c->numbers.home,
            c->numbers.business);
}
```

(**note:** you could have simply passed the struct by-value without using a pointer and used the `'.'` operator throughout, but any time you have numerous members it is more efficient to simply pass a pointer rather than requiring copy of all members)

A short test program could be:

```
int main (void) {

    struct contact mycontact = { .name = {"", "", ""} };

    if (fill_contact (&mycontact))
        prn_contact (&mycontact);
    else
        fputs ("error: filling contact.\n", stderr);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

If you put all the pieces together above, your could exercise the program as follows:

```
$ ./bin/struct_contact

name
 first name     : Mickey
 middle initial : M
 last name      : Mouse

address
 street number  : 1234
 street name    : Looney Tunes Way
 apartment no.  : 1
 postal code    : 90210
 city           : Disney

contact
 cell number    : 3105551211
 home number    : 3105551212
 business no.   : 3105551213

collected information
 Mickey M. Mouse
 1234 Looney Tunes Way, Apt. 1
 Disney, 90210
 cell: 3105551211
 home: 3105551212
 bus.: 3105551213
```

After you write any input routine -- **go try and break it**. Try and find corner cases where your input routine fails, goes into an infinite loop, invoked *Undefined Behavior* by writing beyond your array bounds, etc... For example you could try:

```
$ ./bin/struct_contact

name
 first name     : Mickey
 middle initial : M
 last name      : Mouse (stinking mouse -- who has a last name "Mouse"?)

address
 street number  : 1 2 buckle my shoe 3 4 shut the door
...
```

If it breaks -- go fix it.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Sometimes the best help putting all the individual syntax pieces together is just seeing it done. Everybody needed help getting started.